# Unable to find template in prod

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I just uploaded my application to my webspace, and cleared the cache via ssh. But in the prod environment my log file shows me an exception:

> InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template "Project:News:overview.html.twig". (uncaught exception) at /path/to/my/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 123

Do you have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases the problem is, that windows is not case sensitive and linux is. So check your files and the case sensitivity of your files and folders.

Comment: No problem ;) i had the same problem with a project from a friend. Then you could mark my answer as correct ;)